# powershell update file in subfolders if it already exists

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, copy-item

I can't believe this is as difficult as I'm finding it.

I have a folder on a server share. This folder has a number of subfolder which may, or may not, contain a file I want to overwrite with a latest-version.

I've done many a google search & figured the command below would get me what I want:

```
Get-ChildItem \\server1\websites\website\xml -Name "description-15240.txt" -Recurse | Copy-Item ".\description-15240.txt" -Destination $_.fullname
```

...but it doesn't.

So, I break the command down into parts & find the Get-ChildItem only returns the file path FROM the root of the -Name parameter i.e.

1\infinite\description-15240.txt
  68\infinite\description-15240.txt
  79\infinite\description-15240.txt
  80\infinite\description-15240.txt

rather than \server1\websites\website\xml\1\infinite\description-15240.txt which is what I'm after.

The problem: I can't get the Get-ChildItem to return the full path 
    `| { $_.FullName }` doesn't do it
    neither does `| { $_.Parent }`

Can someone help & possiblly tell me if the `Copy-Item` is likely to work as well?

Many thanks, N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` parameter only filter the name of the file, if you want full path of the file use `include` parameter.

```
Get-ChildItem \\server1\websites\website\xml -include "description-15240.txt" -Recurse | % { Copy-Item ".\description-15240.txt" -Destination $_.fullname }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
gci \\server1\websites\website\xml -Name "description-15240.txt" -recurse |%{ convert-path $_.pspath}
```

Comment: Is this correct? I get a `Convert-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null` error when I try it.